# Search for struct in swift

Tags: ios, swift

Hello i am building a code and i am working with structures. I want to setup the search on the view. Here is what i have so far and what I’m trying to do

```
struct subCategory {
    var subCategoryName = String()
    var subCategoryDesc = String()
    var subImageId = String()
    var subType = String()
    var subLinkType = String()
    var subCatImageUrl = String()
    var subCatId = String()
}

var subCatContent = subCategory()
var subCatArray = [subCategory]()
var filteredsub = [subCategory]()
```

This is my view controller

```
self.resultSearchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
self.resultSearchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
self.resultSearchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
self.resultSearchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.resultSearchController.searchBar
self.tableView.reloadData()
```

This is where the magic is suppose to happen but it doesn’t work because subCatArray isn’t a NSArray so i cant use predicate. How else can i do this?

```
func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController)
{
    self.filteredsub.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
    let searchPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF CONTAINS[c] %@", searchController.searchBar.text!)
    let array = (self.subCatArray as NSArray).filteredArrayUsingPredicate(searchPredicate)
    self.filteredsub = array as! [String]

    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are working with array of `subCategory`, you could use `filter`, for example:

```
filteredsub = subCatArray.filter { 
    $0.subCategoryName == searchController.searchBar.text!
}
```

Comment: U sir are amazing thanks much. I got it working perfect.

Comment: One more question that worked perfect but i have to write out the entire word. Is there a way to check each character so if i am looking for say “TOUR” can i display it when i type “T” or “TO” for example?

Comment: I think this should work: `$0.subCategoryName.containsString(searchController.searchBar.text!)`

Comment: Thank you so much u are amazing. i got working perfact. that was my task completed..